# MS CRM 2011 - custom plugin to share dashboard views

Tags: asp.net, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dashboard

I'm trying to create a MS CRM Dynamics 2011 plugin that shares views in a dashboard when the dashboard is shared with users. Right now, when we share a dashboard, users cannot see the views because the views have not been shared as well.

[image]

I know how to share records with code, but I'm not sure how to hook my plugin to a dashboard share event. Normally I use the Plugin Registration Tool and specify an entity and CRUD operation required to kick off my plugin:

[image]

But because Dashboards are not entities (Contact, Account, etc.), I'm not sure how to fire my plugin during sharing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: message name is probably AssociateRequest
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334669(v=crm.5).aspx

Comment: @achan - Thank you. I'm still not sure what I would put as the Primary Entity. Do you think it would be user?

Comment: nvm, entity is likely userform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out. 
Message: GrantAccess.
Primary Entity: userform